# Configure Git to store files on secondary hard drive

Tags: windows-10, git

I'm installing Git on my home PC, Windows 10.
I would like my sandbox to be on the C: drive.

How do I set up Git to commit (and push) files to my D: drive?

Should I set up Git to commit to the C: drive and push to the D: drive?
(I'd like a backup on another hard drive.}

Or: How to set up my PC as a server using the D: drive?
{This would allow me to create sandboxes on other computers connected to my LAN.}

*Note: I have experience using other SCM tools such as PVCS, PTC Integrity, ClearCase and MS SourceSafe.*

Thanks.

Comment: What's the difference between cloning the git repository in `D:` drive and the question?

Comment: My understanding is that *cloning* creates a sandbox.  At work, when I commit files, they are placed on my `C:` drive.  When I commit files, I want them placed on the `D:` drive.

Comment: How do I set up Git so that the respository is on D: and I can clone to C: drive?

Comment: [Git - First-Time Git Setup](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup)

Comment: [Setting up a repository | Atlassian Git Tutorial](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/setting-up-a-repository)

Comment: [Working with Git on Windows  •  Beanstalk Guides](http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/version-control/git-on-windows.html)

Comment: So in git terms, you want your repository to be on D: and working directory on C:?

Comment: Yes.  When I checkout branches, they will be copied to the C: drive.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike other systems you may have used, Git stores a complete copy of the history when you create a repository.  Therefore, if your working tree is on C:, by default all of your history will be in the `.git` directory under your working tree.  However, you can change that.

If your goal is to store a copy of your history so that you have a backup, you can do that by setting up a remote and pushing to it periodically.  You can create a bare repository on D: with `git init --bare D:/path-to-repository` and add a remote in your working tree on C: using `git remote add origin file:///D:/path-to-repository`.  You can then push branches with a syntax like `git push origin master`.  (It may be possible to use a bare Windows path with backslashes rather than a file URL, but I don't use Windows, so providing the right syntax for Windows is left as an exercise for the reader.)

You can also use the feature called worktrees, in which the main repository is located in one place and a single branch's working tree is located in another.  You can see how to do this with `git worktree --help`.  However, this doesn't really provide a backup; instead, the Git history and object storage is in one place and your working tree is in another.  It also requires creating a new worktree for each branch, which is probably not what you want.

You can clone over the network from another computer if you can run SSH on the server or you can mount a network disk.  In the latter case, you can clone from the bare repository using a normal path instead of a URL.